# Running a python script at build time in CMake, requires no dependencies

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I have a python script h2py.py that converts a header file .hpp to .py file.

I want this python script to be run every time I build my project with CMake.
There is no other project or file that has a dependency on the file generated by the script.

So far I have tried this:

```
find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)

add_custom_target(
 run ALL
 COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/converter/h2py.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/converter/
 COMMENT "Converting .hpp file to .py file"
)

add_dependencies(converter run)
```

But this does not generate the .py equivalent of the .hpp file (specified within the script)

*EDIT* : When I run the python script h2py.py in a terminal, it generates the .py eqvivalent of the .hpp file, just as intended. But it does not generate the .py file when I run the CMake file.

This is the whole CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(converter)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE release)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED
    roscpp
    geometry_msgs
    eigen_conversions
    std_msgs
    tf_conversions
    tf
    genmsg
    message_generation
    sensor_msgs
    rospy
    gazebo_msgs
)

catkin_package(
    #DEPENDS Eigen libpcl-all-dev gnuplot
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp sensor_msgs tf_conversions tf geometry_msgs message_generation
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
    )
###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header fils
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
 include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
 add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/motion_covariance.cpp
   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/tf_utils.cpp
 )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}  )

find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)

add_custom_target(
 run ALL
 COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/converter/h2py.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/converter/
 COMMENT "Converting .hpp file to .py file"
)

add_dependencies(converter run)
```

Comment: "But this does not generate the .py equivalent of the .hpp file (specified within the script)" - Do you mean that your command is **not run** when you build the project? I would found that impossible, since you specify `ALL` keyword for `add_custom_target`. Please, elaborate your case.

Comment: When I run the python script h2py.py in a terminal, it generates the .py eqvivalent of the .hpp file, just as intended. But it does not generate the .py file when I run the CMake file

Comment: Probably, your script isn't prepared to be run from the **build directory**. If you want CMake to run your script from the other directory (e.g. from the source one), add appropriate `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option to the `add_custom_command`. If this doesn't work, then the problem is in your python script, and without viewing it we cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, by setting the WORKING_DIRECTORY it began to work!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per @Tsyvarev's comment, problem was solved by setting the WORKING_DIRECTORY option to the add_custom_command!